# Nginx redirecting to the wrong site; poorly formed server_name directive

Tags: nginx, subdomain

#### The Problem

When you type `example.com` into the address bar of a browser **WITHOUT** entering the scheme, i.e. `http://` or `https://`, Nginx redirects the user to `https://api.example.com` instead of `https://example.com` as intended. I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with my Nginx config, but I'm not sure what.

#### Details

I'm hosting two websites on the same server, with the same IP. The relevant bits from the DNS zone file looks something like (domain and IP anonymized here):

```
example.com. 1800 IN A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
www.example.com. 1800 IN CNAME example.com.
api.example.com. 1800 IN CNAME example.com.
```

I have two SSL certs installed (provided by letsencrypt), one for each site, and both sites are configured to redirect to HTTPS. I have two vhost config files, one for each site, as follows:

- `/etc/nginx/sites-available/api`
- `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Both are symlinked into `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. The relevant bits from the two config files are as follows:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/api
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name api.example.com;
    return 301 https://api.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/api-ssl-params.conf; # ssl config info
    server_name api.example.com;

    # ... the rest of the site config ...
}
```

and:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 default_server ipv6only=on;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf; # ssl config info
    server_name example.com;

    # ... the rest of the site config ...
}
```

I don't understand why just entering `example.com` into the address bar would redirect to `https://api.example.com` because:

1. just plain `example.com` doesn't appear in the `api` config file anywhere
2. `example.com` shouldn't match the `server_name` directive `api.example.com`
3. the server blocks in `default` are marked as `default_server` so shouldn't that take precedence when an ambiguous domain name was typed in?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh. Figured it out in the process of writing the question. The problem is that just plain `example.com` doesn't appear in the `server_name` directive for either of the sites listening on port 80. **Since that causes ambiguity, nginx picks the first site in alphabetic order.**

I updated the config file for the `default` site as follows:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com; # <-- CHANGED THIS LINE
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 default_server ipv6only=on;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf; # ssl config info
    server_name example.com;

    # ... the rest of the site config ...
}
```

And all was right with the universe.

Comment: _nginx picks the first site in alphabetic order_ — not alphabetical, but first in order of appearance while nginx reads config if there is no `default_server` flag. But it reads files from `sites-enabled` in alphabetical (ascii actually) order.